# Change Apache Guacamole URL Path

Tags: apache, tomcat, guacamole

I have recently installed Apache Guacamole on my Centos 8 server. When I try to access the server it uses the following url: `http://10.10.44.11:8080/guacamole/#/` However, I would like to simplify this URL path to something like `http://10.10.44.11/`. In other words, no path after the IP Address.

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out the solution by changing the `<Location>` path, I have tried all combinations possible but have not succeeded.

I have apache version 2.4.37 (centos) as well as tomcat-9.0.48.

By default `/etc/httpd/conf.d/tomcat_manager.conf` contains:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin root@localhost
    ServerName 10.10.44.11
    DefaultType text/html
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

However, I tried to change the variables a bit so it can remove the /path, based on multiple forms to something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin root@localhost
    ServerName 10.10.44.11
    
<Location /> # 
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/guacamole/ flushpackets=on
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/guacamole/
</Location>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Where `"/"` in `<Location />` means NO-PATH

The problem is that I have not been able to successfully change the PATH at all... I am not an expert in apache, so perhaps I am doing something wrong?

If it is important: the location of my `guacamole.war` is at `/etc/guacamole`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, by default, access to the bastion host is done by ending the URL with `/guacamole`. It is however possible for your case to redirect the URL so that the bastion host is accessible only by entering the URL http://10.10.44.11:8080

To do this, you must first go to the "/var/lib/tomcat*/webapps/ROOT" directory and move the "index.html" file to another directory

```
#cd /var/lib/tomcat*/webapps/ROOT

#mv index.html .......
```

Then, in a second step, you have to create an index.jsp file in which you enter the following configuration:

```
<% response.sendRedirect("/guacamole");%>
```

Finally, just restart the tomcat service. Changes should be taken into account.